# Setup simple bluetooth server console?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi i wanna work with some bluetooth communication using my Android device.
How can i test bluetooth connections easy?

Let say im creating a simple application that will send the message "Hello World" upon connection. I would like some sort of server application console i could fire up on my iMac and have my android application connect to.

The server application should just be a console or something that displays all the data it receives and maybe a input to back a response.

Is there anykind of program that allow this ?
Or do i really need 2x android devices to create a simple server / client interaction with bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [Android Bluetooth Chat App](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) will be good starting point .
you can make this connect to the mac over serial port profile.

The example above is for the latest Android versions (it is possible to accomplish this with 1.x versions of android also, you will have to use the appropriate api that are supported in older android versions also)

For Programming in the Mac refer to [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH216-TPXREF113)

Comment: Hi Dennis, how am i able to run the android chat application ón my Mac , im pretty sure the emulator does not support bluetooth.

Comment: The default MAC software implements a Serial port profile, you can hook up a serial port terminal client to the MAC SPP serial port and display / write data to it Or On the Mac you will need to write your own application / server (See link above).