# Android Bluetooth testing App

Tags: android, bluetooth

Ive written a test app based off the Bluetooth Chat app. What is the best way to test that, just to see if the connect is being made ect. with out the having a second device? So something like a Bluetooth Server with logging for Mac. (The test app is a Bluetooth Client)

Robert

Comment: Apparently you can't use bluetooth with the emulator (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175076/how-to-use-bluetooth-in-android-emulator So you can create a script on your computer to test it if your computer has bluetooth. Otherwise you have to test it with a friend.

Comment: You should follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444389/setup-simple-bluetooth-server-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your client test app on an Android device, on the Server side you can use the Bluetooth on your Mac.

Comment: Are there any applications that I can download that can be used as a server. Or would I need to write a BT Server?

Comment: you can use the Bluetooth preferences option on the MAC and setup a serial port on the mac - then use any terminal emulator (like Zterm) to attach to the Bluetooth Serial port... then your android client foul due able to see this serial port on the mac and connect to it .. the messages that the android client sends can will be displayed on the Zterm.

Comment: Awesome, do you know whether it logs or says that a connection has been made before any messages are sent?

Comment: you can log it at your client application